# Scroll content between two points

Tags: html, css

I need to scroll a sidebar div and it's content (3 links) vertically between two points. I have used **position:fixed; top: 100px**.  This works fairly well, it starts 100px down form the top and scrolls vertically when a user scroll down the page. But how do I get it to stop just before the footer?   So far I have:

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidebar">
<div class="scroll">
<ul>
<li>Link 1</li>
<li>Link 2</li>
<li>Link 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.scroll {position: fixed; top: 450px;}
```

Thanks,

Andy ;-)

---

Okay, I have added more code to give a better picture of what I am after.   Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mwt4x90d/

The javascript should be placed before the closing scroll div of the HTML file.  However, jsfiddle wants it separated out.

I got it working, but I have two issues.  The first is the **outer div (sidebar) collapses** (just see a line above the scroll div.  The second is the **div is not stopping above the Left Box / Pagination** no matter what figure I use inside the parenthesis. I am using a Liquid layout so maybe that is having an effect.

If anyone can see what I am doing wrong, it would be great, I don't know JavaScript, so I am just going by what ye say here.  Thanks for any help, Andy ;-)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Scrolling Sidebar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="mainstyle.css">
        </head>
<body>
<div class="headerContents">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>

<div class="leftM"></div>
    <div class="centerM">
        <a class="top"></a>
                <aside>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eu euismod nisl, ac dignissim libero. Aenean gravida justo in nunc blandit ultrices. </p>
                    </div>
                </aside>
                <aside>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eu euismod nisl, ac dignissim libero. Aenean gravida justo in nunc blandit ultrices. </p>
                    </div>
                </aside>
                <aside>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eu euismod nisl, ac dignissim libero. Aenean gravida justo in nunc blandit ultrices. </p>
                    </div>
                </aside>
    </div>
<div class="rightM"></div>

<div class="sidebar">
<div class="scroll">


    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript>
  var footP = 0;
  var scroller = document.getElementsByClassName("scroll");
  setInterval("if(document.body.scrollTop > (350) && footP == 0){scroller[0].style.position = 'absolute';scroller[0].style.top = document.body.scrollTop + 450;footP = 1;};",1);
  setInterval("if(document.body.scrollTop <= (350) && footP == 1){scroller[0].style.position = 'fixed';scroller[0].style.top = 450;footP = 0;};",1);
  </script>
</div>
</div>

<div class="cards">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eu euismod nisl, ac dignissim libero. Aenean gravida justo in nunc blandit ultrices. Aenean risus arcu, tristique id tortor nec, suscipit commodo risus. Aenean ac fringilla lorem. Cras eu euismod est, sit amet vulputate turpis. Fusce in felis sed lectus tincidunt posuere. Cras in sapien ut metus tincidunt laoreet eget ac ex. Cras congue nec enim in dictum.<p>

<p>Duis urna sapien, tristique non leo non, ultricies iaculis nibh. Sed posuere quis eros vitae vestibulum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas auctor sollicitudin condimentum. Pellentesque ipsum lacus, convallis sed nunc et, porta lacinia lectus. Nam vitae ante erat. Etiam elementum velit quis neque vehicula, quis blandit quam pulvinar. Vestibulum mollis pretium tortor porttitor accumsan. Proin nec semper nulla. Praesent mi augue, placerat vitae auctor vel, lobortis eget dolor. Donec eget mi augue. Maecenas eu augue cursus, maximus nisi eleifend, tempor lacus. Curabitur quis dolor vel urna venenatis pellentesque a nec est. Duis sit amet tempus dui. Integer egestas luctus efficitur. Etiam efficitur orci et ullamcorper pulvinar.<p>

Duis eleifend metus nibh, vel vulputate est mattis sit amet. In interdum fermentum lorem, in consectetur eros pretium bibendum. Curabitur turpis diam, molestie nec accumsan sed, scelerisque nec orci. Cras lobortis rutrum sem, vel viverra magna scelerisque ac. Phasellus convallis nunc quis consectetur congue. In vestibulum erat non tellus aliquam sodales. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras quis rutrum augue, in faucibus nisi. Nulla bibendum ut massa vel eleifend. In nec ligula eget nisi ultricies eleifend. Aliquam ac finibus enim. Maecenas at lacus dictum, porta neque non, suscipit ex. Aenean sem nisl, pellentesque vel leo eget, volutpat condimentum odio. Curabitur sed dui nulla.
</div>
<div class="leftp">Duis eleifend metus nibh, vel vulputate est mattis sit amet. In interdum fermentum lorem, in consectetur eros pretium bibendum. </div>
<div class="pag snippetspag"> 
                    <ul class="pagination">
                      <li><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">&laquo;</a></li>
                      <li><a class="active" href="../page1.php">1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="page2.php">2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="page3.php">3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="page4.php">4</a></li>
                      <li><a href="page5.php">5</a></li>
                      <li><a href="page6.php">6</a></li>
                      <li><a href="page7.php">7</a></li>
                      <li><a href="javascript:history.go(1)">&raquo;</a></li>
                    </ul>
          </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
                <aside>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eu euismod nisl, ac dignissim libero. Aenean gravida justo in nunc blandit ultrices. Aenean risus arcu, tristique id tortor nec, suscipit commodo risus. Aenean ac fringilla lorem. Cras eu euismod est, sit amet vulputate turpis. Fusce in felis sed lectus tincidunt posuere. Cras in sapien ut metus tincidunt laoreet eget ac ex. Cras congue nec enim in dictum.</p>
                    </div>
                </aside>

                <aside>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eu euismod nisl, ac dignissim libero. Aenean gravida justo in nunc blandit ultrices. Aenean risus arcu, tristique id tortor nec, suscipit commodo risus. Aenean ac fringilla lorem. Cras eu euismod est, sit amet vulputate turpis. Fusce in felis sed lectus tincidunt posuere. Cras in sapien ut metus tincidunt laoreet eget ac ex. Cras congue nec enim in dictum.</p>
                    </div>
                </aside>

                <aside>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eu euismod nisl, ac dignissim libero. Aenean gravida justo in nunc blandit ultrices. Aenean risus arcu, tristique id tortor nec, suscipit commodo risus. Aenean ac fringilla lorem. Cras eu euismod est, sit amet vulputate turpis. Fusce in felis sed lectus tincidunt posuere. Cras in sapien ut metus tincidunt laoreet eget ac ex. Cras congue nec enim in dictum.</p>
                    </div>
                </aside>

                <aside>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eu euismod nisl, ac dignissim libero. Aenean gravida justo in nunc blandit ultrices. Aenean risus arcu, tristique id tortor nec, suscipit commodo risus. Aenean ac fringilla lorem. Cras eu euismod est, sit amet vulputate turpis. Fusce in felis sed lectus tincidunt posuere. Cras in sapien ut metus tincidunt laoreet eget ac ex. Cras congue nec enim in dictum.</p>
                    </div>
                </aside>
</div>
<div class="copyright">
<p class="copyrightText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="index.php">Lorem Ipsum</a> 2016</p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
 @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,700italic,300,700);
    body{
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: #3f3f3f;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        color: #000;
        background: #f4f3f2;}

    h1{font-size: 2.8em; font-weight: 700;} 
    h2{margin: 0 0 .5em 0; font-size: 1.4em; font-weight: 700; line-height: 1.1em;}
    h3{margin: 0 0 .5em 0; font-size: 1.3em; font-weight: 700;} 
    p{margin: 0 0 1em 0;}

    .headerContents{background-color: #3f3f3f; padding: 1em 2em; margin-bottom: 2em;}
    .leftM, .centerM, .rightM{
        float: left; 
        margin-bottom: 2em; 
        margin-left: 3%;}
    .centerM{background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;}
    .leftM{width: 9%;}
    .centerM{width: 68%;}
    .rightM{width: 9%;}
    .sidebar,.cards{
        float: left; 
        margin-bottom: 1em; 
        margin-left: 3%;}
    .sidebar {width: 21%; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; background-color: #fff;}
    .scroll{position: fixed; height: 200px;}
    .cards {width: 70%;}
    .leftp, .pag{
        float:left;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
        margin-left: 3%;}
    .leftp{clear: both; width: 21.5%;}
    .pag{width: 69.5%; background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; padding: 1.5em 0;}
    .footer{
        clear: both;
        padding: 1.5em 1em; 
        background-color: #3f3f3f; 
        overflow: hidden;
        line-height: 1.5em; 
        border-top: 5px solid #ff0000;
        color: #fff;}
    .copyright{clear:both;}

    .headerContents h1{font-size: 3em; color: #fff;}
    .centerM aside{width: 33%; float: left; text-align: center;}
    .centerM .content{
        margin: 15px;
        background: no-repeat center top;
        background-size: 75px 75px;
        padding-top: 15px;}
    .centerM aside h2{text-decoration:none;}
    .centerM aside h2:hover{text-decoration: underline;}

    .snippetspag{
        text-align: center;}

    ul.pagination {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;}

    ul.pagination li {display: inline;}

    ul.pagination li a {
        color: #3f3f3f;
        float: left;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 5px;}

    ul.pagination li a:hover {
        color: #ff0000;}

    ul.pagination li a.active {
        background-color: #ff0000;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 5px;}


    .footer aside .content{
        margin: 0 auto; 
        width: 22%; 
        float: left; 
        text-align: left; 
        margin-left: 3%;}
    .footer a:link, a:visited{color: #99cc00; text-decoration: none;}
    .footer a:hover, a:active{color: #cc9900;}  
    .copyright{
        text-align: center; 
        background-color: #3f3f3f; 
        padding: 1%; 
        border-bottom: 5px solid #ff0000;}
    .copyrightText{font-size:0.9em; color: #fff;}
    .copyrightText a:link, a:visited{color: #99cc00; text-decoration: none;}
    .copyrightText a:hover, a:active{color: #cc9900;}
```

Comment: take a look at http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/

Comment: or share more code

Comment: @CommercialSuicide, you mean, _write_ more code? I doubt he has more than that.

Comment: Neato, looks good Simon, I will check it later tonight when I get a chance and report back ;-)

Comment: I added more code to the original post to give a better overview of what I am after.  The sidebar div which holds a scroll div needs to be able to move freely as a user scrolls, but only between the centerM and leftP divs.  So I would go with the Javascript example given by @ZekeYoung below if I could get it to work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert this a the end of your HTML:

```
  <script type="text/javascript>
  var footP = 0;
  var scroller = document.getElementsByClassName("scroll");
  setInterval("if(document.body.scrollTop > (ENTER FOOTER POSITION HERE) && footP == 0){scroller[0].style.position = 'absolute';scroller[0].style.top = document.body.scrollTop + 450;footP = 1;};",1);
  setInterval("if(document.body.scrollTop <= (ENTER FOOTER POSITION HERE) && footP == 1){scroller[0].style.position = 'fixed';scroller[0].style.top = 450;footP = 0;};",1);
  </script>
```

So that basically changes the position to stay where it is when it gets to the footer position.

REMEMBER TO ENTER THE FOOTER POSITION IN IN A STANDARD NUMBER FORM.

Like 600.

Not 600px.

```
    <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="scroll">
    <ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:2500px">
    </div>
    <style>
    .scroll {
    position: fixed;
    top: 450px;
    }
    </style>

    <script>
    var footP = 0;
    var scroller = document.getElementsByClassName("scroll");
    setInterval("if(document.body.scrollTop > (600) && footP == 0){scroller[0].style.position = 'absolute';scroller[0].style.top = document.body.scrollTop + 450;footP = 1;};",1);
    setInterval("if(document.body.scrollTop <= (600) && footP == 1){scroller[0].style.position = 'fixed';scroller[0].style.top = 450;footP = 0;};",1);
    </script>
    </body>
```

That's the entire thing.

And it might not work on JSFiddle. Just copy that into a Notepad++ HTML file and edit all you want!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Just, tried this, where exactly do I place it?  I put it at the end of the code before the last closing div.  Nothing seems to happen.

Comment: I suggest putting it at the end of all of the HTML, but still in the body. So you have your sidebar, and you put it after that.

Comment: Thanks again, that worked to a point.  I have updated the code in the original example to show a full page example.  At the minute, the sidebar div is collapsing and while the scroll div scrolls, it does not stop above the Lorem Ipsum Box / Pagination.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Andy help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so I have no idea what the Lorem Ipsum Box is, but you just have to replace all of the 600s that I put there and change them to be where the scroll div should stop scrolling. Also, delete the div with 1500 as its height. I just used the tall div and the 600s as an example to show that it worked. You did notice that I edited the answer, did you?

Comment: Yip, I saw the edit.  I did both those things, deleted the height and changed the 600. However, I must have copied the code incorrectly, I just copied again, and it is working.  Thanks very much for your help ;-)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help  ;-)